# Backbone per instance event bindings

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a view that creates a sub-view per item in the list.  Generically let's call them ListView and ListItemView.  I have attached an event as follows on ListItemView:

```
events: {
    "click .remove": "removeItem"
}
```

I have template-generated html for ListItemView that is approximately like the following (swapped lb/rb for {/} so you can see the "illegal" html):

```
{div class="entry" data-id="this_list_item_id"}

    SOME STUFF HERE

    {div class="meta"}

        {a class="remove" href="javascript:;"}[x]{/a}

    {/div}

{/div}
```

The problem is, when the click on any of the [x]'s, ALL of the ListItemViews trigger their removeItem function.  If I have it go off of this model's id, then I drop all the items on the page.  If I have it go off the clicked item's parent's parent element to grab the data-id, I get a delete for EACH ListItemView instance.  Is there a way to create an instance-specific event that would only trigger a single removeItem?

If I have ListView hold a single instance of ListItemView and reassign the ListItem model and render for each item in the list it works.  I only end up with one action (removeItem) being triggered.  The problem is, I have to find the click target's parent's parent to find the data-id attr.  Personally, I think the below snippet is rather ugly and want a better way.

```
var that = $($(el.target).parent()).parent();
```

Any help anyone gives will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your view code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `events` hash is on your ListView.

If it is, then you can move the `events` hash to ListItemView and your `removeItem` function can be the following

```
removeItem: function() {
  this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
}
```

If this isn't the case, can you provide your ListView and ListItemView code so I can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess but possible; check that your rendered html is valid. It might be possible that the dom is getting in a tiz due to malformed html